# How can I implement this PHP code in Java Servlet

Tags: java, javascript, php, servlets

I am trying to upload images via a drag and drop interface, I got the JavaScript code [here](http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/08/file-uploader/) but the server side code is implemented in PHP as shown below (I modified it to insert the image to database):

```
<?php

//Connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "something-strange") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("business_clax") or die(mysql_error());

// The posted data, for reference
$file = $_POST['value'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

if(!isset($file))
{
    echo "Please select an image.";
}

//This is the line of code I really want in Java
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($file)); //SQL Injection defence!
$image_name = addslashes($name);
$sql = "UPDATE `adverts` SET `photos` = '{$image}' WHERE `id` = '1'";
if (!mysql_query($sql)) { // Error handling
    echo "Something went wrong! :(";
}

?>
```

The code above is working very well but I need to implement this in Java.
I tried to implement the code above in a Java Servlet but I have no idea how to do the `file_get_contents($file)` and the `addslashes(file_get_contents($file));` functions in Java, I think there must be an equivalent method. Please I need help. Thanks.

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_file_uploading.htm

Comment: It might help if you post the Servlet code so far.  Having said that, you probably want `Connection`'s [`.createBlob`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html#createBlob()) and `Blob`'s [`.setBinaryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html#setBinaryStream(long)) methods if you're storing files in the database.  Assuming these are blob fields, that is.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `byte[]` representation of a file, I would look at the Apache FileUtils library, specifically the `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(java.io.File file)` method.

To get the `String` representation of the file, use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(java.io.File file)` (You also need to know about java files.)

Also, the `java.sql.PreparedStatement` object guards against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: The question is how can I get the file like the `file_get_contents($file)` function is doing?

Comment: How can I do that in a Java servlet? Also can I say `request.getParameter("value")` the way PHP is doing `$file = $_POST['value'];`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHP, but I'm very familiar with Java.  Would you mind telling me what that function does? Then I could tell you what Java code to use.  (I assumed that the function you used returned the bytes of the file.)

Comment: Okay.  Use the same library (FileUtils), but use the readFileToString method.

Comment: I will get back to you on that, let me check the online documentation.

Comment: It says [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) that it "Reads entire file into a string"

Comment: The argument is the filename. So I guess what I need is a method in Java that get's the file from the request via the file name. Can you help me on that?

Comment: If you are getting the filename from a parameter, create the `File` like this: `java.io.File file = new java.io.File(request.getParameter("nameOfParameterGoesHere"));`